# Azure recovery services backup single drive

Tags: linux, azure, recovery-services

Is there any way to specify disks that I want to backup from Azure Linux VM with Azure Recovery Services? I know that Recovery Services makes a snapshot of a Linux VM and from Azure Portal I can't customize it other than just backup schedule but maybe using Powershell or Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to specify disks that I want to backup from Azure
>   Linux VM with Azure Recovery Services?

Based on my knowledge, for now, Azure only supports backup file or folder(drive) on Windows. Because if you want to back up files and folders to Azure, you need  install and register the Recovery Services agent. However, the agent does not support Linux VM now.

I think you need to know how to [backup file or folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-try-azure-backup-in-10-mins) and how to [restore file or folder on Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-restore-windows-server).

Comment: This is not entirely true, Azure Recovery Services supports backup of Linux VMs - it is file consistent backup when VM is running and crash consistent when VM is stopped. More information here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup#linux-support and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm#install-the-vm-agent-on-the-virtual-machine. Question is if I can customize the snapshot that is produced when backing up Linux VMs

Comment: @TomaszTuczapski  Yes, you could backup full Linux VM by using Azure Recovery Services. However, you could not backup exclude disks on Linux VM

Answer (score -1):

At this point, you can't select or exclude disks while doing a VM level backup in AZURE.